# POST request using F#

Tags: https, f#

I want to make a POST request with a body containing a simple key value pair
like `{ "Id":"VVE87BDA-B0A1-48F3-A7C7-F3482CE2UIJ" }`
How can I do this in F# ??

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FSharp.Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/Http.html) library

```
Http.RequestString
  ( "http://httpbin.org/post", 
    headers = [ ContentType HttpContentTypes.Json ],
    body = TextRequest """ {"test": 42} """)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this through .NET libraries like in C# or VB. Here's how it works with `HttpWebRequest` (assuming you aren't using `task` or `async`):

```
let obj = {| Id = "VVE87BDA-B0A1-48F3-A7C7-F3482CE2UIJ" |}

let req = WebRequest.CreateHttp "http://www.example.com"
req.Method <- "POST"
req.ContentType <- "application/json"

do (
    use reqStream = req.GetRequestStream()
    use sw = new StreamWriter(reqStream )
    obj |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> sw.Write
)

use resp = req.GetResponse()
use respStream = resp.GetResponseStream()
use sr = new StreamReader(respStream)
let respBody = sr.ReadToEnd()

printfn "%s" respBody
```

`async` version:

```
let obj = {| Id = "VVE87BDA-B0A1-48F3-A7C7-F3482CE2UIJ" |}

let req = WebRequest.CreateHttp "http://www.example.com"
req.Method <- "POST"
req.ContentType <- "application/json"

do! async {
    use! reqStream = req.GetRequestStreamAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
    use sw = new StreamWriter(reqStream )
    do! obj |> JsonConvert.SerializeObject |> sw.WriteAsync |> Async.AwaitTask
}

use! resp = req.AsyncGetResponse()
use respStream = resp.GetResponseStream()
use sr = new StreamReader(respStream)
let! respBody = sr.ReadToEndAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask

printfn "%s" respBody
```

In either case it's best to make sure reqStream goes out of scope and gets disposed before the GetResponse call, to make sure the request data gets fully written.